# RTF - Where can I find the text content?

Tags: sql, sql-server, rtf

I am querying an MSSQL server for some information and I am getting the following:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1251\deff0\nouicompat
    {\fonttbl
        {\f0\fnil\fcharset204 Calibri;}
        {\f1\fnil Calibri;}
    }
```

I understand this is RTF, but I cannot find the content, which should be this:

```
ПЕЧАТЕЊЕ ЗА ВУРТ
```

How does this work? How does the above generate the text?

Comment: What you show us is - for sure! - not the whole content... How did you retrieve this? Where and how did you read this?

Comment: @Shnugo The table has invoices, and there is a column called acNote that has comments about the invoice. I am very confused about the actual comment not being there, but it displays fine in the UI. I also don't see anything linking to the comment. Black magic?

Comment: Please answer the questions: Where/How do you read this? SSMS for example will cut off any textual output for performance reasons. You'd have to set a higher limit.

Comment: @Shnugo You are right. I ran the query in SSMS and I got the same value. However, when I copied and pasted it in notepad, it displayed the full content. It does appear to have a limit on the characters. How can I increase the limit to display the full thing? The data also has new lines. Does that affect anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You are right. I ran the query in SSMS and I got the same value.
>   However, when I copied and pasted it in notepad, it displayed the full
>   content. It does appear to have a limit on the characters. How can I
>   increase the limit to display the full thing?

Do a right click into the query window and choose `options`. The following dialog allows to specify a text's max length. The highest value allowed is 8192.

> The data also has new
>   lines. Does that affect anything?

Press `<ctrl>+T` to swap from "Results to Grid" to "Results to Text". This will write the entire content as text and you will see line breaks (within the grid line breaks are ommitted)

**Hint** Reduce your `SELECT` to only one textual column!

Comment: Thanks. I guess I have some coding to do in order to display everything properly.

Comment: @Ivan This depends on: How and where do you try to dsiplay this value?